# Retrofit and RxJava cannot serialize Json Data properly

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have response from an API that looks like this,

```
    {
  "stop-schedule": {
    "stop": {
      "key": 10064,
      "name": "Northbound Osborne at Glasgow",
      "number": 10064,
      "direction": "Northbound",
      "side": "Nearside",
      "street": {
        "key": 2715,
        "name": "Osborne Street",
        "type": "Street"
      },
      "cross-street": {
        "key": 1486,
        "name": "Glasgow Avenue",
        "type": "Avenue"
      },
      "centre": {
        "utm": {
          "zone": "14U",
          "x": 633838,
          "y": 5525742
        },
        "geographic": {
          "latitude": "49.86912",
          "longitude": "-97.1375"
        }
      }
    },
    "route-schedules": [
      {
        "route": {
          "key": 16,
          "number": 16,
          "name": "Route 16 Selkirk-Osborne",
          "customer-type": "regular",
          "coverage": "regular"
        },
        "scheduled-stops": [
          {
            "key": "8131173-23",
            "times": {
              "arrival": {
                "scheduled": "2018-02-02T23:07:20",
                "estimated": "2018-02-02T23:07:20"
              },
              "departure": {
                "scheduled": "2018-02-02T23:07:20",
                "estimated": "2018-02-02T23:07:20"
              }
            },
            "variant": {
              "key": "16-0-B",
              "name": "Selkirk-Osborne to Tyndall Park via Burrows"
            },
            "bus": {
              "bike-rack": "false",
              "easy-access": "true",
              "wifi": "false"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "8131174-24",
            "times": {
              "arrival": {
                "scheduled": "2018-02-02T23:32:20",
                "estimated": "2018-02-02T23:32:20"
              },
              "departure": {
                "scheduled": "2018-02-02T23:32:20",
                "estimated": "2018-02-02T23:32:20"
              }
            },
            "variant": {
              "key": "16-0-M",
              "name": "Selkirk-Osborne to Tyndall Park via Manitoba"
            },
            "bus": {
              "bike-rack": "false",
              "easy-access": "true",
              "wifi": "false"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "8131175-23",
            "times": {
              "arrival": {
                "scheduled": "2018-02-02T23:57:20",
                "estimated": "2018-02-02T23:57:20"
              },
              "departure": {
                "scheduled": "2018-02-02T23:57:20",
                "estimated": "2018-02-02T23:57:20"
              }
            },
            "variant": {
              "key": "16-0-B",
              "name": "Selkirk-Osborne to Tyndall Park via Burrows"
            },
            "bus": {
              "bike-rack": "false",
              "easy-access": "true",
              "wifi": "false"
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "8131176-24",
            "times": {
              "arrival": {
                "scheduled": "2018-02-03T00:22:20",
                "estimated": "2018-02-03T00:22:20"
              },
              "departure": {
                "scheduled": "2018-02-03T00:22:20",
                "estimated": "2018-02-03T00:22:20"
              }
            },
            "variant": {
              "key": "16-0-M",
              "name": "Selkirk-Osborne to Tyndall Park via Manitoba"
            },
            "bus": {
              "bike-rack": "false",
              "easy-access": "true",
              "wifi": "false"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "query-time": "2018-02-02T22:48:55"
}
```

I am using retrofit to make a request using the RxJava method. However, Gson doesn't seem to recognize the nested parts of my data and put it in the appropriate Model.

```
Retrofit retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

My Models look like this

```
    public class StopSchedule implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("query-time")
    private String mQueryTime;
    @SerializedName("route-schedules")
    @Expose
    private List<RouteSchedule> mRouteSchedules;
    @SerializedName("stop")
    private Stop mStop;
    @SerializedName("stop-schedule")
    private StopSchedule mStopSchedule;

    public String getQueryTime() {
        return mQueryTime;
    }

    public List<RouteSchedule> getRouteSchedules() {
        return mRouteSchedules;
    }

    public Stop getStop() {
        return mStop;
    }

    public StopSchedule getStopSchedule() {
        return mStopSchedule;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private String mQueryTime;
        private List<RouteSchedule> mRouteSchedules;
        private Stop mStop;
        private StopSchedule mStopSchedule;

        public StopSchedule.Builder withQueryTime(String queryTime) {
            mQueryTime = queryTime;
            return this;
        }

        public StopSchedule.Builder withRouteSchedules(List<RouteSchedule> routeSchedules) {
            mRouteSchedules = routeSchedules;
            return this;
        }

        public StopSchedule.Builder withStop(Stop stop) {
            mStop = stop;
            return this;
        }

        public StopSchedule.Builder withStopSchedule(StopSchedule stopSchedule) {
            mStopSchedule = stopSchedule;
            return this;
        }

        public StopSchedule build() {
            StopSchedule StopSchedule = new StopSchedule();
            StopSchedule.mQueryTime = mQueryTime;
            StopSchedule.mRouteSchedules = mRouteSchedules;
            StopSchedule.mStop = mStop;
            StopSchedule.mStopSchedule = mStopSchedule;
            return StopSchedule;
        }

    }
}
```

I also have `RouteSchedule` class model and other class models. However, after the normal response from retrofit using a single, my RouteSchedule model is empty.

Is there a way I can get route-schedule array alone or make sure it doesn't return an empty model.

Comment: So what happens when you construct this object just using: `Gson.fromJson(yourResponseString, StopSchedule.class)` (syntax might be off slightly - from memory)? Same can be done for the nested object, just parse the relevant section of the Json string.

Comment: add your pojo classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in here.

```
@Expose
private List<RouteSchedule> mRouteSchedules;
```

`@Expose` is used to use the same fields names which is different from your JSON.

so remove the  `@Expose`.

```
@SerializedName("route-schedules")
private List<RouteSchedule> mRouteSchedules;
```

Comment: use gson for this my friend